# How to print list of links through Python Selenium

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

New to Python and Selenium and trying to print all of the links found in a specific category. For some reason it is only taking the first listing and repeating it. Could someone help please?

The gist of the code is the webdriver navigating to the page I need. The important part is at the end where I try to loop and get all the links.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

    # create instance of Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.skelbimai.lt/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/skelbimai/technika/mobilus-telefonai']")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/skelbimai/technika/mobilus-telefonai']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-query']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-query']").send_keys("nokia 3310")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='search-place']").click()

city_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='search-place']")
city_target = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='19']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", city_target)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
city_target = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='19']")))
city_target.click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()

listing_results = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='classified ']")

for x in range(2):
    print(listing_results.get_attribute('href'))

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, nothing was changing per iteration. You want this instead:

```py
listing_results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='classified ']")

for listing_result in listing_results:
    print(listing_result.get_attribute('href'))
```

---

You can also use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to simplify your entire script to:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_base(self):
        self.open("https://www.skelbimai.lt/")
        self.click("//a[@href='/skelbimai/technika/mobilus-telefonai']")
        self.click("//button[@mode='primary']")
        self.type("//input[@id='search-query']", "nokia 3310")
        self.click("//select[@id='search-place']")
        self.click("//option[@value='19']")
        self.click("//button[@type='submit']")
        listing_results = self.find_elements("//a[@class='classified ']")
        for listing_result in listing_results:
            print(listing_result.get_attribute("href"))
```

(If you `pip install seleniumbase` and then run the above script with `python` or `pytest`.)